# Logging metrics for go grpc server

Tags: go, logging, grpc, interceptor

This is kindof an extension of my previous question [Reuse log client in interceptor for Golang grpc server method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74831707/reuse-log-client-in-interceptor-for-golang-grpc-server-method/74832675#74832675).

Basically I have a grpc server (written in Go) that exposes three APIs:

- SubmitJob
- CancelJob
- GetJobStatus

I am using Datadog to log metrics, so in each API, I have code like:

```
func (s *myServer) submitJob(ctx context.Context, request *submitJobRequest) (*submitJobResponse, error) {
    s.dd_client.LogRequestCount("SubmitJob")
    start_time := time.Now()
    defer s.dd_client.LogRequestDuration("SubmitJob", time.Since(start_time))

    sth, err:= someFunc1()
    if err != nil {
        s.dd_client.LogErrorCount("SubmitJob")
        return nil, err
    }

    
    resp, err:= someFunc2(sth)
    if err != nil {
        s.dd_client.LogErrorCount("SubmitJob")
        return nil, err
    }


    return resp, nil
}
```

This approach works but have several problems:

- The `LogRequestCount` and `LogRequestDuration` is duplicated among all APIs
- I am calling `LogErrorCount` in every places where errors are returned, which seems ugly

I learned that interceptor might help with logging, so I wrote an interceptor like

```
func (s *myServer) UnaryInterceptor(ctx context.Context,
    request interface{},
    info *grpc.UnaryServerInfo,
    handler grpc.UnaryHandler,
) (interface{}, error) {
    // Get method name e.g. SubmitJob, CancelJob, GetJobStatus
    tmp := strings.Split(info.FullMethod, "/")
    method := tmp[len(tmp)-1]

    s.dd_client.LogRequestCount(method)

    start_time := time.Now()
    resp, err := handler(ctx, request)
    server.dd_client.LogRequestDuration(method)

    if err != nil {
    s.dd_client.LogErrorCount(method)
    }

    return response, err
}
```

And set it in main() function:

```
server := grpc.NewServer(grpc.UnaryInterceptor(my_server.UnaryInterceptor))
```

This works for me, but I noticed two problems:

- Here the interceptor takes myServer as a receiver, is this a good practice? I am doing this coz I want to reuse the Datadog client (dd_client) created within myServer. Other options would be create the Datadog client singleton which used by both interceptor and myServer, or create a interceptor struct and create a separate Datadog client there.
- The interceptor could only handle logging for generic metrics e.g. request count, duration. But there could be metrics specific for each API, which means I still need to have logging related code in each API implementation. Then the question is, should I still use interceptor? Coz now the logging related code are splitted into two places (API implementation and interceptor).